# Find F(x) given f(x)

Tags: probability

Given the pdf:

$$f(x) = \frac{k}{\lambda}\left(\frac{x}{\lambda}\right)^{k-1}e^{-\left(\frac{x}{\lambda}\right)^k}, x \geq 0.$$

Find F(x)

My first step is to let $u=(\frac{x}{\lambda})^k$, so f(x) becomes:

$f(x) = \frac{k}{\lambda} u^{-1}e^{-u}$

I then integrate f(x) from 0 to infinity (since $x \geq 0$):

$F(X) = \int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{k}{\lambda} u^{-1}e^{-u} du$

I take out $\frac{k}{\lambda}$

$ \frac{k}{\lambda}  \int_{0}^{\infty}u^{-1}e^{-u} du$

Then using integration by parts: 
$ \frac{k}{\lambda} \times  (-u^{-2}e^{-u})|_{0}^{\infty} - 1$

And then I get stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand your substitution steps, from where comes $$e^{-u}$$

Comment: As an aside, this is the [Weibull distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution).

Comment: You should review the calculations from your substitution. If $u= \left(\frac{x}{\lambda}\right)^k$, you  should find what $du$ is.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I understand where I went wrong.

Comment: You're welcome $\ddot{\smile}$! Also to find $F(x)$, make sure you only integrate up to $x$, not to $\infty$. (So just find $\displaystyle \int_0^{\color{red}{x}} f(t)\, dt$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your substitution choice is sensible, but you miscalculated what happens. You should find $$\int_0^x f(x^\prime) dx^\prime=\int_0^{(x/\lambda)^k}\exp -u du=1-\exp\left[-\left(\frac{x}{\lambda}\right)^k\right].$$

Comment: Can you please show me how you got $(x/\lambda)^k$?

Comment: @Dr.Doofus In integrating up to $\infty$, you would have only ever obtained $1$, the total probability. But $F(x)$ integrates only up to $x$, or (after this substitution) $(x/\lambda)^k$.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes, I understand that, but if $u = (\frac{x}{\lambda})^k$, then wouldn't $x = u^{\frac{1}{k}}\lambda$ ?

Comment: @Dr.Doofus $$\int_0^x g^\prime(h(x^\prime))h^\prime(x^\prime)dx^\prime=\int_{h(0)}^{h(x)}g^\prime(u)du=g(h(x))-g(h(0)).$$I think you might need more practice integrating by substitution.

Comment: You're right. Thank you. It's been a while.